# I want to link 2 php files together by clicking a button

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have 2 php files and I want to link the two files by clicking a button .. so if I click a button in the first php file it should transfer my to the second php file ..

1st php file and here I want to click s & P Database button :

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> My System </h1>
<form action="">

<input type="button" value="S & P Database ">
<input type="button" value="Generate Report  ">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

2nd php file that I should have it when the button is clicked :

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="">
<h4><b>Please choose one of the following options below : </b> </h4>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="search" /> Search<br/>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="open database" /> Open Database<br/>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="administrative page "/> Administrative Page     <br/>
</form>
// This button doesn't appear in the web page =( .. dunno why 
<form action="">
<input type="button" value="Choose ">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: name the button and check its value when submitted? AND put action as the second php file. so it wont GET to itself

Comment: The first problem you have is that your forms have no actions as such the pages will just do nothing, also you have no code to link the button to an action since only a `submit` will submit a form, also there is no PHP here only HTML.

Comment: But I named the button and give them a value, am I ??

Comment: yes but only a `<input type='submit' value='submit this form'/>` will actually submit the form without JS

Comment: Yeah now I only write on HTML but I need the php for the other stuff like the database.. so please could u tell me where and how could I add action to the forms and button .. sorry but really I'm beginner to these stuff ..

Comment: I would use @newfurniturey answer since these buttons look like they do nothing more than what links normally would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to redirect the user to the second page when the button on the first page is clicked.

To simply redirect the user, you can use the button's `onclick`:

```
<input type="button" value="S & P Database" onclick="window.location.href='page2.php'" />
```

Comment: It is also work with the radio button if I have this code :     <html>
<body>
<form action="">
<h4><b>Please choose one of the following options below : </b> </h4>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="search" /> Search <br/>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="open database" /> Open Database<br/>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="administrative page "/> Administrative Page <br/>
</form>
// This button doesn't appear in the web page =( .. dunno why 
<form action="">
<input type="button" value="Choose ">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" onClick="window.location='/2nd.php'" value="S & P Database ">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This will redirect you to /2nd.php

Answer (score 0):

simple Put

> method="post" or method="Get"

and in action type the name of 2nd file which in your case will be

> action="2ndfile.php(what ever its name is)"

also in cahnage your button to submit

> 

keep in mind that this action script is for your 1st file.

Comment: Wont work since the buttons will not submit the form I dont think, you must use a explicit `submit` type to submit forms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add link to php nahdler in action attribute

so it will be `<form action="http://www.website.com/1.php">`

Input type should be "image" or "submit", button will not submit your form.

You can also submit form by JS, but i will not describe how to do that here.

Use right document structure and doctype: http://www.rantiev.com/doctypes/
Check your code with validator: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input 
When some elements dissapear it can be that HTML have errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this:

2 forms submitting to different locations

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> My System </h1>
<form action="page2.php" method="get">
    <input type="button" name="pressed" value="S & P Database ">
</form>
<form action="page3.php" method="get">
    <input type="button" name="pressed" value="Generate Report  ">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

2 links to different locations

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> My System </h1>
<a href="page2.php?pressed=sp">S & P Database</a>
<a href="page3.php?pressed=report">Generate Report</a>

</body>
</html>
```

1 form with name and values of buttons. But your script (page2.php) will need to check the value of $_GET['pressed'] too

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> My System </h1>
<form action="page2.php" method="get">
    <input type="button" name="pressed" value="S & P Database ">
    <input type="button" name="pressed" value="Generate Report  ">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

BUT dont forget to urldecode($_GET['pressed'])) as the values will be encoded.